# How to get Fuel result outside of the fuel call

Tags: android, api, kotlin

I'm working on a **kotlin** app on Android and I'm using Fuel to get data from a REST API.

I want to fill my ***ArrayList*** with the data from my API.

But if I debug my code, after going inside the *Fuel* part, my ArrayList is still empty (but it's not empty if I print it inside Fuel).

Why ? And how can I get the result outside the Fuel part ?

```
val receivedAlerts = ArrayList<String>()
var jsonArray : JSONArray
val resultActus = Fuel.get(Constants.urlAlertes).responseJson { request, response, result ->
    Log.i(TAG, result.get().obj().toString())
    result.fold({
        json ->
        jsonArray = JSONArray(json.content)

        if(jsonArray.length() > 0){
            (0 until jsonArray.length()).forEach {
                val item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(it)
                val id = item.getString("ID")
                receivedAlerts.add(id)
            }
        }
    }, {
        err ->
        Log.i("error", err.toString())
    })
}
    Log.i(TAG, "from getReceivedAlerts $receivedAlerts")
```

No one knows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fuel is working on a background thread, which means the function returns before your array is filled.

Example:

Function call:

```
fun sendToAPI(context: Context, data: someData, f: () -> Unit)
```

as you can see, in the function call we pass a function as a parameter(f), this will be usefull later.

```
SomeURL.httpPost(formData)
        .response { _, _, result -> result.fold(
            success = {
                // Save data in the array
                // Runs function
                f()
                context.showToast("success")
            },
            failure = { error ->
                context.showToast(error.message!!)
            }
        ) }
```

Basically, in the success statement you want to save your array, You can do so in different methods, I personally like to have a singleton which stores all my data (you can create one with the object keyword in kotlin)

Then we run the function passed as a parameter, where you want to get the data out of the singleton and do what you want with it.

Comment: Is it possible to do it in local ArrayList ? (in the class only) ? I tried, but didn't worked.

Comment: @MorganTartreau I would save it in the local array like you are doing now, then run a local function that takes it out of the array and does whatever you need to do with it!

Comment: That's what I've ended up with, now I know that Fuel works in a background Thread, I missed that.

Comment: @MorganTartreau Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

By default Fuel makes the call asynchronously. Personally I like using fuel synchronously and handling async in a different part of my application.

```
val (request, response, result) = "$yourUrl".httpGet().response()
```